# Shouldn't the change of user name be signalled to all people who posted in relation to the former name?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

People change their names from X to Y, but their older name is mentioned in answers and comments (like "as X explained in his answer" - while there's no link to the answer that now is signed by Y).

Comment: [i have a new meta-question ;) - "how can a bad question receive good answers?"]

Comment: There's even a badge for it.  I think someone who isn't me may have thought it sounded like complaining instead of questioning.

Comment: so, i need a badge or an answer :)

Comment: Did you post the feature request on MSO?

Comment: @Call me V - did not. but was just joking. that's all there is to it. (thanx again for your involvement in the vlc extension: i like it a lot!)

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be for the user's profile to have a field listing the older name, for some number of days. (30 would be reasonable.)

When referring to a *post* rather than a person, it's usually best to link to that post. Of course, not everyone does that. (This is something people may wish to consider when changing their names.)

Answer (score 2):

I think [this is related to me changing my name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267670/saving-subtitles-found-by-the-vlc-extension-subtitle-finder/267726#267726).  Consider what happens if that takes place.  I have 500 questions/answers combined.  They don't need to know when I change my name.  It would be a nuisance.

Comment: i am curious about the matter in general, i have nothing against changing name :) - and i guess is useful to hear more ideas on this

Comment: On the referred to in comments bit, that might be an interesting architectural change to field on MSO.  Shouldn't tagged users not show up as strings, but as :user_id in source and be replaced by the appropriate username to remain in context after name changes? type of thing.